# bind el valor de tagExpression en una función de Azure

Tags: c#, azure

Tengo una función en Azure que se lanza al insertar un mensaje en Service Bus, y quiero que como output se encadene un llamado a mi Hub de notificaciones de Azure.

Este es el código de la función:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class NotificacionMedicina
{
    public string medicacion { get; set; }
    public string deviceID { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<string> Run(string medicacion,
                                     IAsyncCollector<Notification> medicacionMSG,
                                     TraceWriter log)
{
    NotificacionMedicina med=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificacionMedicina>(medicacion);

    await medicacionMSG.AddAsync(new AppleNotification(med.medicacion));

    return med.deviceID;
}
```

El código funciona si no intento enviar un tagExpression pero se manda a todos los dispositivos registrados en el hub de notificaciones.

Me gustaría saber como enlazar ese valor, ya que con $return no funciona (intenté modificar la función para que tomará el valor de retorno pero marca error)

Este es el valor de function.json:

```
{
     "bindings": [
     {
       "name": "medicacion",
       "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
       "direction": "in",
       "queueName": "getwellqueue",
       "connection": "getwellbus_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS",
       "accessRights": "manage"
     },
     {
       "type": "notificationHub",
       "name": "medicacionMSG",
       "hubName": "GetwellPushNotificaciones_DEV",
       "connection": 
    "GetwellPushNotificacionesDEV_DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature_NH",
      "direction": "out",
      "platform": "apns",
      "enableTestSend": false,
      "tagExpression": "" // ESTE ES EL VALOR QUE QUIERO BINDEAR
     }
   ],
    "disabled": false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví usando el [binding en el runtime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#imperative-bindings), hay algunas refencias mas a detalle [aquí](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-functions-to-make-audit-queue-and-auditors-happy)

Con esta solución se pasa un parámetro tipo Binder o IBinder, en el que se crea una referencia a la salida deseada (en este caso un elemento para un Hub Notification APS) y se liga dinámicamente, esto permite emular a la salida que se genera declarativamente en el archivo function.json pero con los valores que se desean.

El código de la función quedaría así:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.NotificationHubs"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class NotificacionMedicina
{
    public string medicacion { get; set; }
    public string deviceID { get; set; }
}
public static async Task Run(string medicacion,
                         IBinder binder,
                         TraceWriter log)
{ 
     NotificacionMedicina med=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificacionMedicina>(medicacion);

    var attribute = new NotificationHubAttribute
    {
        ConnectionStringSetting = "GetwellPushNotificacionesDEV_DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature_NH",
        HubName = "GetwellPushNotificaciones_DEV",
        Platform = Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationPlatform.Apns,
        TagExpression = med.deviceID
    };

    IAsyncCollector<Notification> notifications = binder.Bind<IAsyncCollector<Notification>>(attribute);
     await notifications.AddAsync(new AppleNotification(med.medicacion));
}
```

En el archivo function.json se elimina la referencia a la función de salida y queda así:

```
{
   "bindings": [
   {
      "name": "medicacion",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "getwellqueue",
      "connection": "getwellbus_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS",
      "accessRights": "manage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```